# Arduino Uno - WebService (AzureML)

Tags: web-services, azure, arduino-uno, azure-machine-learning-service

I'd like to connect to an AzureML Web Service. I have looked into the POST Method on the Arduino Homepage and also here https://iotguys.wordpress.com/2014/12/25/communicating-with-microsoft-azure-eventhub-using-arduino/

Here is my Setup method:

```
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      while (!Serial) {
      ; // wait for serial port to connect.
      }

     Serial.println("ethernet");

     if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
       Serial.println("ethernet failed");
       for (;;) ;
     }
    // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
    delay(1000);
 }
```

The Post Method is based on this: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebClient

I just added `sprintf(outBuf, "Authorization: Bearer %s\r\n", api_key);` to the header, with `char* api_key = "the ML Web Service API KEY"`

Also, unlike specified in the WebClient I use the whole WebService URI as url and do not specify a page name.

This doesn't work.

The Network to which I am connecting has Internet Access.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine Learning Studio services that you create needs to receive requests from a device that has SSL capabilities to perform HTTPS requests. AFAIK, Arduino doesn't support SSL capabilities.

One usual scenario is to attach the Arduino to a third device like Raspberry Pi 2 etc to use it as a gateway and do the call from the Pi itself.

Here's a sample [project](https://github.com/Azure/connectthedots/blob/master/GettingStarted.md) from Microsoft Open Technologies team that utilizes Arduino Uno, Raspberry pi and Azure stuff.

Hope this helps!